# I need a word or phrase that refers to the fact that your suffering is for the benefit of another

Tags: single-word-requests

One whose suffering is not because of who s/he is, but God has given that person to suffer for the benefit of another.

Comment: there is a meaning of "martyr" that means essentially this, but the word's other meanings more related to those that sacrificed themselves for religion and zealous adherents to causes would distract from that meaning. "Sacrifice"  could be used to convey this although it's not always one for another unless specified.  Like maybe: *The mother sacrificed her own career to move her child to a state with a special school to care for them*.